# How can I set Stackify Prefix to ignore a site?

Tags: iis, stackify

I have installed [Stackify Prefix](https://stackify.com/prefix/) and it's working great. The only problem I have is that I have a CRM site in my IIS. I would really need to ignore this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the list of traces you see very easily.

[image]

The web app name is one of the values that can be used in the filters.  While this doesn't remove the CRM from being profiled, you will at least only see requests in the list that you care about.  This doesn't filter the timing in the graph however.

Sounds like a good feature we can ask for however. I'll pass it on.